# To calculate discounted revenue in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I want to calculate a formula using IF function that should be a progressive 10% discount for each $10M above $40M up to a maximum of 50%. 
Examples: 
If

```
IF(C22<40000000,0,IF(C22-40000000<=10000000,(C22-40000000)*0.1,
IF(C22-50000000<=10000000,(C22-50000000)*0.2+10000000*0.1,
IF(C22-60000000<=10000000,(C22-60000000)*0.3+10000000*0.1+10000000*0.2,
IF(C22-70000000<=10000000,(C22- 
70000000)*0.4+10000000*0.1+10000000*0.2+10000000*0.3,
IF(C22-80000000>0,(C22- 
80000000)*0.5+10000000*0.1+10000000*0.2+10000000*0.3+10000000*0.4,"- 
"))))))
```

But wanted to know if there was an easier/less complex way for the same.

Comment: Hi K. Could you please provide any code of yours. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I calculated using the formula:=IF(C22<40000000,0,IF(C22-40000000<=10000000,(C22-40000000)*0.1,
IF(C22-50000000<=10000000,(C22-50000000)*0.2+10000000*0.1,
IF(C22-60000000<=10000000,(C22-60000000)*0.3+10000000*0.1+10000000*0.2,
IF(C22-70000000<=10000000,(C22-70000000)*0.4+10000000*0.1+10000000*0.2+10000000*0.3,
IF(C22-80000000>0,(C22-80000000)*0.5+10000000*0.1+10000000*0.2+10000000*0.3+10000000*0.4,"-"))))))

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `IFS` Function instead of `IF` . The IFS function checks whether one or more conditions are met, and returns a value that corresponds to the first TRUE condition. IFS can take the place of multiple nested IF statements, and is much easier to read with multiple conditions. [MS SUPPORT IFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45)

I have shown basis of my calculation of discount in the snapshot Assuming Unit Price $1 so that logic can be checked. Tables of calculation are self explanatory and can be adjusted by you as per your preferences. Put Sale Volume in Cell `D2` and Formula in `E2`

```
    =IFS(D2>90,0.16667,AND(D2>80,D2<90),0.1667,AND(D2>70,D2<80),0.125,AND(D2>60,D2<70),0.085714,AND(D2>50,D2<60),0.05,AND(D2>40,D2<50),0.02,D2<40,0)
```

[image: calculate discount]

Working file has been uploaded [soq_54785817](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0xrqnafm0hmha1/soq_54785817.xlsx?dl=0) , which can be referred for any doubt,

Comment: Thank you @skkakkar this is really helpful!!

Comment: @K.Gurjar Glad that my answer helped you. Please accept my answer by ticking a check-mark in the left side of answer and below the down pointing triangle. check mark will fill up when you tick it. Stack Overflow way of saying thanks by accepting the answer.